# How to throw 404 error in a Zend Expressive?

Tags: php, zend-framework, mezzio

I have a problem.
I need to throw a 404 error when I do not get a $item (see code).

```
class HomeHandler implements RequestHandlerInterface
{
    private $template;
    private $dataService;

    public function __construct(
        Template\TemplateRendererInterface $template = null, 
        DataServiceInterface $dataService
    ) {
        $this->template = $template;
        $this->dataService = $dataService;
    }

    public function handle(ServerRequestInterface $request) : ResponseInterface
    {
        $alias = $request->getAttribute('alias', '');

        $item = $this->dataService->getItem($alias);

        if(!isset($item)) {
            // Here you need to throw 404 error
        }

        return new HtmlResponse($this->template->render('app::home-page', $item));
    }
}
```

I use Zend Expressive 3.

Grateful for any of your thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a HTML response with a specific status code:

```
if (!$item) {
    return new HtmlResponse($this->template->render('error::404'), 404);
}
```

adjust the template to point at whichever is appropriate.

Comment: This is the easiest way. Other options are (1.) creating a custom ErrorHandler with 404 support and throw a 404 Exception if an item is not found, or (2.) injecting the NotFoundHandler into the handler and call it directly: `$this->notFoundHandler->handle($request)`, or (3) convert it to a middleware and call `return $handler->process($request)` (which will trigger the NotFoundHandler).

Comment: or you can send it on header information: `$requestResponse = $request->withHeader('HTTP',404);
                return $handler->handle($requestResponse);`